# I have smoothed normals at a bevelled edge; how are these edges still this blatantly visable?

Tags: normals, bevel

In the second image you can see by the light blue lines where I marked edges to be sharp, and the orange faces I have selected I applied Mesh>Normals>Average>FaceArea. In the third image you can see the faces/edges around this curve do not smooth out completely, the inside smaller curve does though. I have also tried setting normals from faces, it has the same effect as seen here in the third image. How are these edges not getting smoothed out completely? Is there any way I can smooth them without the edges being so visible?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are shots of attempting HISEROD's solution:
[image]
[image]

Here is HISEROD's solution taken to a more extreme and creating too much geometry, but with very good visual results:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have auto-smoothing enabled?  If so what's the angle set to?

Comment: Yes,It comes on as soon as I try to average the normals of the faces. It is set to the default 30. Additionally, I tried moving it from 0 degrees to as far as 180 and it doesn't appear to change anything. If I turn off auto-smooth I lose any of the smoothing between the edges of course.

Comment: I believe that this interpolation problem is caused by the stretched quads. Adding an edge loop near the inner edge might fix it.

Comment: I just tried it out but it didn't seem to change anything for the faces in the large curve at first when I placed it near the small curve edge. However, once I started adding more loop cuts near the center I started seeing more obvious improvements near the cuts. Overall it does look better, I was hoping to not need to add more geometry but if this is the best option I will certainly take it. Thank you very much Hiserod.

Edit: I forgot to mention, I did the face average, then did the loops, then did the face average again of the faces shown in the new images I have added to initial post.

Comment: please share this part of your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/